# Get the foreground app in Android 6.0.1. UsageStatsManager.queryusagestats returns empty list in version 6.0.1

Tags: android, usagestatsmanager

The below code worked fine till version 6.0

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    UsageStatsManager mUsageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
                    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    List<UsageStats> stats = mUsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, currentTime - 100 * 1000, currentTime);
                    if(stats != null) {
                        long lastUsedAppTime = 0;
                        for (UsageStats usageStats : stats) {
                            if (usageStats.getLastTimeUsed() > lastUsedAppTime) {
                                String foregroundApp = usageStats.getPackageName();
                                lastUsedAppTime = usageStats.getLastTimeUsed();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Now the queryUsageStats return empty list.

Is there any other way to get the foreground app ?

Note: Added the below permission to retrieve the usagestats

```
<uses-permission xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For Android 6.0.1 you need to reconfigure your code to get the Android Permissions Framework working for your app.

You can refer this link for getting more information on this.
[Android Permissions Development for Android 6.0.1 (Marshmallow)](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en)

Comment: Thanks Shadab..!! That was really informative. But even after granting the permission manually in 6.0.1 UsageStatsManager did not work.

Comment: I have shifted to Accessibility service and used TYPE_WINDOW_CHANGED to get the foreground app which is version independent. For now, I can think of this solution itself. Please let me know if there is any other possible way..

Answer (score 0):

It's a late reply, but hope it will help others.

go to System Settings, search for 'Data Usage Access', and enable that for you app, you will receive a non-empty list.